# Best way to validate currency input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have created the TextBox and CompareValidator below which I thought would allow input in the following forms:

- 5
- 5.00
- $5.00

Unfortunately it's not allowing the version with the dollar sign in it.  What is the point of doing a type check against currency if you don't allow the dollar sign?  Is there a way to allow this symbol?

```
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_CostShare" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CostShare", "{0:$0.00}")%>' CausesValidation="true" />
            <asp:CompareValidator   ID="vld_CostShare" 
                                    runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="tb_CostShare" 
                                    Operator="DataTypeCheck" 
                                    Type="Currency" 
                                    ValidationGroup="vld" 
                                    ErrorMessage="You must enter a dollar amount for 'Cost Share'." />
```

Comment: What if you use `{0:c}` instead?

Comment: A currency validation could include currencies other than USD...

Comment: @Austin - I don't want to validate anything other that USD.  @Greg - How would I use {0:c} to validate?

Comment: I don't know, maybe it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Why do you want the dollar sign in the validation? You should just be validating the data `5.35`. If you want to display the $ sign, place a label on the front of the text box. That way you can also store it as a decimal in SQL.

Comment: I want to accept user input if it has a dollar sign or not.  What I am displaying is a separate issue that is already being handled properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CompareValidator doesn't support currency symbols. You can prefix your input control with the $ or use a regular expression validator, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998267.aspx) page has an example.

The following pattern will match your examples (courtesy of http://www.regexlib.com):

```
^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could write a custom validator to parse the string, with or without $. But you would need to write some Javascript to get any client side validation.