# Validate currency format in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I would like to validate whether a string satisfy the following currency format with maximum 4 decimal places and could allow comma `,` *regardless of culture* and *the comma could be at places of standard practice*.

Eg:

```
2,000,000(valid)  
200000.0000(valid)  
200 (valid)  
200.00000(invalid)
```

How could it be done?

Comment: Check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182858/validating-my-money). Here is [**another one**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693832/best-way-to-validate-currency-input). If these did not help, a regular expression may be, is'nt ?!

Comment: You get the decimal separator via `[CultureInfo].NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`. Now I'm sure there is a nice RegEx for that, but you might also be able to do it like `string[] parts = value.Split(new string[] {decimalSeparator}); bool isValid = parts.Length <= 1 || parts[1].Length <= 4;`

Comment: Regex `^\d+(\,\d+)*(\.\d{1,4})?$` might work for you. Demo https://regex101.com/r/lD4eZ5/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `Regex` match for your purpose.

The `Regex` below works for your specific examples. But, it'll accept comma `,` at random places. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD4eZ5/1) here.

```
^\d+(\,\d+)*(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

A better `Regex` would be the following. Check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG2jL0/1). Base Regex taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693832/best-way-to-validate-currency-input) post.

```
^\$?(\d{1,3},(\d{3},)*\d{3}|\d+)(.\d{1,4})?$
```

**Update**

To answer comment - above `Regex` allows `0090`. Try this one. Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/tW7aX8/1).

```
^((([1-9]\d{0,2},(\d{3},)*\d{3}|[1-9]\d*)(.\d{1,4})?)|(0\.\d{1,4}))$
```

**Update 2**

C# usage

```
var currencyString = "1,234,456.7890";
var regex = @"^((([1-9]\d{0,2},(\d{3},)*\d{3}|[1-9]\d*)(.\d{1,4})?)|(0\.\d{1,4}))$";
var isValidCurency = Regex.IsMatch(currencyString, regex);
```

**Update 3**

As per OP, comma `,` is allowed at any place. Updated `Regex` with demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/yY9zD1/1).

```
^(([1-9]\d*(\,\d+)*(\.\d{1,4})?)|(0\.\d{1,4})|0)$
```

**Update 4**

Use this one. Demo [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/tE8rV4/1).

```
^((([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)(\.\d{1,4})?)|[1-9]\d*|(0\.\d{1,4})|0)$
```

Well, [this](https://regex101.com/r/tE8rV4/2) :)

```
^((([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d{1,4})?)|[1-9]\d*|(0\.\d{1,4})|0)$
```

Comment: it pass with the following: 0200

Comment: How to use it in C#?   Regex regex = new Regex(@"/^([1-9]\d{0,2},(\d{3},)*\d{3}|[1-9]\d*)(.\d{1,4})?$/gm"); this seems not working as expected. Neither do it work if i remove gm

Comment: Please see the updated answer and updated Regex. For single string you can ignore gm flags.

Comment: hi thanks for the feedback. But it doesnt work for this case. 1000,000 and
1,000000

Comment: I didn't understand you'd allow comma at any place! See update 3.

Comment: Hmm. I think i did not explain it clearly. I mean that the update 2 validation pass for 1000,000 and 1,000000. What i would like to achieve is either the comma is allow in every 3 digit before decimal, or don't allow at all. eg: 1,000,000 (pass) 1000,000(fail) 1,000000(fail), 1000000(pass)

Comment: @vincentsty there was an mistake. Please see update 4 :)

Comment: hi 20000000.0000(fail). should pass

Comment: Different cultures have different decimal separators ([NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx)) and thousand separators ([NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx)) and users can even create their own custom ones. So I strongly suggest you to use the appropriate ways of finding them out and using them, instead of "guessing" where a `','` or `'.'` might be allowed or not.

Comment: @vincentsty I had already updated the answer. It works fine. Please check again (the last regex and link).

Comment: @Corak true. But the OP specifically wants a format irrespective of culture. Mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ArghyaC - Yes, and I argue that working on string representations of decimal values without taking the culture into consideration is not good for sanity in the long run. Even then, work with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, which seems to be what OP want's to do implicitly. And even if it's really fixed, I'd argue that `string[] parts = value.Split('.'); bool isValid = parts.Length <= 1 || parts[1].Length <= 4;` is more readable than that RegEx. ^_^

Comment: @Corak I agree on the Culture part and maintainability in long run. Apart from that, the code you gave is plain wrong. No offense, just try it once :)

Comment: @ArghyaC - wouldn't say "plain wrong". It works very well for the original question. It fails on checking "comma is allowed in every 3 digit before decimal, or don't allow at all", though (i.e. returns a false positive).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94431/discussion-between-arghya-c-and-corak).